# Swift code to force led flashlight when a devise receives a push notification

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am working on an application that receives push notifications. Is there a code in swift to activate the LED flash for Alerts when sending a push notification even though this option was not turned on in the user's device?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to turn flashlight ON and OFF in swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207278/how-to-turn-flashlight-on-and-off-in-swift)

Comment: you can do it only if the notification is received when your app is currently in foreground