# iOS: Is it possible to trigger the LED flash for alerts programmatically?

Tags: ios

This is an accessibility setting within the app:
[image]

Can this flash be triggered in iOS?

Comment: see this for help :[Demystifying iPhone’s Amber Flashlight](https://medium.com/@thatchaponunprasert/demystifying-iphones-amber-flashlight-519352db10bd)

Comment: is this the one u r looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207278/how-to-turn-flashlight-on-and-off-in-swift